# Efficient way to ensure data is present for react component using redux to manage state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

## Background

I am using redux to manage the state of my react application. Using `redux-api-middleware` I get data from an external api. Since these calls are synchronous components will be rendered whilst there is no data.

I am checking all of the data before I render everything but I think that it looks so messy because some of the data is a little complex.

## Example

Here is an example of the way I am checking for the data in the render method.

```
render () {
    let data = this.props.data ? this.props.data : false;
    let dataInner = data ? data.get('inner') : false;

    let dataInnerThing = dataInner ? dataInner.get('thing') : false;

    let dataOtherThing = dataInner ? dataInner.get('other') : false;

    return (
        <div>

             <InnerComponent data={dataInnerThing} />

             <OtherComponent data={dataOtherThing} />

        </div>
    );
}
```

## Problem

The example above isn't so bad but with a container component that has more sub components and more data sources it gets really messy.

## Question

Is there a cleaner way to test for data at every level? Like some separate function to keep the render clean?

Comment: What about connecting the subcomponents to redux as well, and make the verification inside each one. Also I think you can use shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle method.

Comment: ShouldComponentUpdate has nothing to do with my question. That is already taken care of. But in regard to your other suggestion, never/avoid passing data to a component just mapStateToProps of what I need on a component level. That could be a way to reduce clutter.